# Unable to work with union in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation, union

Hi friends am trying to combine one column in one table with column in other table
but am getting error.
Here is code

```
table names are table1 and table2
```

table1 having column name and table2 having column title

```
 table1
 were
 you
 when

 table2
 how
 yes
 no
```

My php and mysql code is as follows

```
$query="SELECT name FROM table1 UNION ALL select title from table2";
$select_playlist=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_playlist))
 {
    $title=$row['title'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    echo $title.$name;
 }
```

Its showing error Undefined index: name

Expected output is

```
 were how
 you yes
 when no
```

If I remove name and print only title its printing as

```
     were
     you
     when
     how
     yes
     no
```

Comment: union combine two column as a one. so you can get data in only $row['title']. if you want to use $row['name'] . you  should write two different query. But looking your coding, you need to join two table

Comment: The operation which would potentially give you the output you seem to want is a _join_ rather than a `UNION`.  That being said, in order to do a join, you would need to be able to _relate_ the name and title columns, to match them up in a meaningful way.  Maybe you should post the full table definitions.

Comment: You need a JOIN for that not a UNION. And for that join you need to tell the database to join on a condition, for example a column in both tables with the same value.

Comment: if I write different query how can I use it mysqli_fetch

Comment: @verhie I dont have common field

Comment: but, how does mysql know which name matches with a title if  any field is common?

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is not possible using these tables.

What you need is a JOIN: JOINs append columns from Table B to Table A.
A UNION appends ROWs from Table B to Table A.

To use a JOIN, the Database needs to know which ROWs belong together, because basically there's no implicit order of the rows in the table.

Table 1:

```
id name
1  were
2  you
3  when
```

Table 2:

```
id title
1  how
2  yes
3  no
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING(`id`)
```

and the result will look like:

```
id name    title
1  where   how
2  you     yes
3  when    no
```

(DBA's: Please don't blame me for sloppy Terms - speaking of tuples and sets here would confuse the user)